# Why is this pushing the row twice into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't find the reason why this is pushing the row twice into the array.
I got 2 sheets that meet the first loop's criteria and in one of them only 1 row meets the criteria, but this is appearing twice in the array:

```js
function summarize() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var rangeData = ss.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var sss = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var searchRange = sss.getRange(5, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);

  // Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
  var exclude = ["Combined", "Categories", "Category", "Entries", "ProfitLoss", "GoBank"];

  //Finds the next empty cell in the destination sheet
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Combined');
  var TargetCol = destSheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var maxIndex = TargetCol.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
    return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);

  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var dataArray = []
    .map(function(el) {
      return [el];
    });

  //Iterates over the sheets
  for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s];

    // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if (exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName()) == -1) {

      // Loop through a range within the sheets that meet above criteria
      // checks if this sheet's rows meet both criteria below
      for (a = 1; a < lastRow - 5; a++) {
        if (rangeValues[a][1] != '' && rangeValues[a][13] != "Yes") {
          dataArray.push(rangeValues[a]);
          var setRow = parseInt(a) + 5;
          sheet.getRange(setRow, 14).setValue("Yes");
        }; //end of row basis iteration
      };
    }
  } // end of sheet basis loop


  //Writes the arry to a sheet.
  destSheet.setActiveRange(destSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1, dataArray.length, 14)).setValues(dataArray);
} // end of function
```

I'd appreciate if you could point me to the direction.

Thanks.

Comment: This: `var dataArray = [].map(function(el) { return [el];});` doesn't do anything. Just use `dataArray = []`

Comment: The cause is likely due to the variable counter `a` not being reinitialized. Add `let` to the internal `for()` ( `for( let a = 1;...)` )

Comment: Hi, @RandyCasburn ! The problem persist, even after the changes above. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: The only thing left then, based upon all your assertions so far, is the condtions in the loop - They are not producing the result you expect and should be tested with a debugger to determine the actual values involved.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, r, I've run a test and it's iterating over the inner for loop as many times as there are sheets whose names meet the outter loop's criteria, not considering then if the inner loop's criteria are met or not. Can't wrap my head around a way out, though. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the basic cause of the inner loop iterating too many times is caused by only setting `lastRow` once - and it is for the active sheet, not the iterated sheet.

Move the assignment of `lastRow` into to outer loop to resolve the issue.